# How to modify the text being pasted?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, paste

I'm trying to modify the text being pasted inside a `TEdit` descendant.

When the user paste some text, I want to replace all 'X' chars with an 'Y', without modifying the actual clipboard text content.

I've intercepted the `WM_PASTE` message, but I'm not aware about any "clean" way to change the text that's being pasted into the control.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TMyEdit = class(Vcl.StdCtrls.TEdit)
  private
    procedure WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste); message WM_PASTE;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses
  Clipbrd;

procedure TMyEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Edt : TMyEdit;
begin
  Edt := TMyEdit.Create(Self);
  Edt.Top := 10;
  Edt.Left := 10;
  Edt.Parent := Self;
end;

end.
```

The only working way I've found is to temporarly replace the clipboard content, but I'm looking for a cleaner solution (if there's one...).

```
procedure TMyEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
var
  PrevClipboardText : string;
begin
  if(IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_TEXT)) then
  begin
    PrevClipboardText := Clipboard.AsText;
    try
      Clipboard.AsText := StringReplace(Clipboard.AsText, 'X', 'Y', [rfReplaceAll]);
      inherited;
    finally
      Clipboard.AsText := PrevClipboardText;
    end;
  end else
  begin
    inherited;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The current approach does not honor [which format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats) is currently in the clipboard - if it is a bitmap or else you'll ruin it, because you always imply text and then reassign text.

Comment: You're right, updated. Anyhow, it is just an example for the approach, I would prefer to avoid changing the clipboard content at all, if it's possible

Comment: If you name your class `TEdit` then you can still add your custom code, but also drop a TEdit onto the form..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do the obvious thing?

```pascal
procedure TEdit.WMPaste(var Msg: TWMPaste);
begin
  SelText := F(Clipboard.AsText);
end;
```

where `F` is your string-transforming function.

Comment: Don't forget the `IsClipboardFormatAvailable()` check: `if IsClipboardFormatAvailable(...) then SelText := F(Clipboard.AsText);` Just note that `Clipboard.AsText` expects `CF_UNICODETEXT` in D2009 and later, and `CF_TEXT` in D2007 and earlier.